# Camel Netty Load Balancer - No Response Received Exception

Tags: apache-camel

I am running into an unexpected `CamelExchangeException` with Apache Camel, Netty4 component, and load balancing. While the code is working fine and the response is returned, Camel still throws `CamelExchangeException` on the last exchange when a Netty connection closes.

```
 from("netty4:tcp://localhost:9090?sync=true&textline=true")
      .setBody(simple("pong"))
      .setHeader(NettyConstants.NETTY_CLOSE_CHANNEL_WHEN_COMPLETE, simple("true", Boolean.class));

 from("timer:foo?delay=10000")
      .to("log:inbound?showAll=true")
      .process((Exchange exchange) -> {
           exchange.getIn().setBody("ping");
       })
       .loadBalance(new LoadBalancer())
       .to("netty4:tcp://localhost:9090?sync=true&textline=true")
       .end()
       .to("log:outbound?showAll=true");
```

Here is the load balancer

```
public class LoadBalancer extends SimpleLoadBalancerSupport {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        this.getProcessors().get(0).process(exchange);
    }
}
```

Exception

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException: No response received from remote server: localhost:9090. Exchange[ID-DESKTOP-6JJUOT9-1529441233240-0-21]
at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.handlers.ClientChannelHandler.channelInactive(ClientChannelHandler.java:133)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:377)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:342)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1409)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:927)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:822)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The same exception is not thrown if load balancer is taken out or connection is to remain open.

Camel version 2.21.1

Comment: Are you asking a question? I think this is a bug for Camel. We had the same issue and we just catch that CamelExchangeException and continue on with the route.